# Derivative $\frac{d\left\{B(A_1, \ldots, A_M)\right\}}{d\left\{C(A_1, \ldots, A_M)\right\}}$ equals what?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, differential

**Question**:

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dB}{dC} = ?
\end{equation}

**Context**

The present problem might be considered a practical exercise with respect to the ongoing discussion in [1].  In addition, [2] offers a related question in that both the question here and there are derivatives with respect to a function.

**Given**:

\begin{align}
A & = f{\left(A_1, \ldots, A_M\right)} =   \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{A_k} = \textrm{constant  
}\\
B & = g{\left(A_1, \ldots, A_M\right)} =   \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{B_k(A_k)} 
\\
C & = h{\left(A_1, \ldots, A_M\right)} =   \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{C_k(A_k)} 
\end{align}

**Approach I: Ratio of Two Differentials**:

The differentials of $A$, $B$, and $C$, are respectively written as
\begin{align}
dA & =  \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{dA_k} = 0 \quad\quad  \textrm{Eq. 1}
\\
dB & =  \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{\dfrac{\partial{B_k}}{\partial{A_k}}}  \, dA_k \quad\quad  \textrm{Eq. 2}
\\
dC & =  \sum_{k = 1}^{M}{\dfrac{\partial{C_k}}{\partial{A_k}}}  \, dA_k \quad\quad  \textrm{Eq. 3}
\end{align}

Next, arbitrarily singling out the $M$th differential, $dA_M$, we rewrite Eq. 1 as
\begin{align}
dA_M & =  -\sum_{k = 1}^{M-1}{dA_k}
\end{align}
and continue to rewrite Eqs. 2 and 3 as
\begin{align}
dB & =  \sum_{k = 1}^{M-1}\left[\dfrac{\partial{B_k}}{\partial{A_k}}  - \dfrac{\partial{B_M}}{\partial{A_M}} \right]  \, dA_k
\\
dC & =  \sum_{k = 1}^{M-1}\left[\dfrac{\partial{C_k}}{\partial{A_k}}  - \dfrac{\partial{C_M}}{\partial{A_M}} \right]  \, dA_k
\end{align}

Naively or not, I write the derivative as the ratio of the differentials. My solution is thus
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dB}{dC} = \dfrac{\sum_{k = 1}^{M-1}\left[\dfrac{\partial{B_k}}{\partial{A_k}}  - \dfrac{\partial{B_M}}{\partial{A_M}} \right]  \, dA_k}{\sum_{k = 1}^{M-1}\left[\dfrac{\partial{C_k}}{\partial{A_k}}  - \dfrac{\partial{C_M}}{\partial{A_M}} \right]  \, dA_k}.
\end{equation}

**Approach II: Chain Rule**:

From [3], let $A=A(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_M) = \textrm{constant}$,   $B = B(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_M)$, and $C =  C(A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_M)$, then the partial derivative of $C$ with respect to $B$, holding $A$ constant, written $\left(\dfrac{\partial{C}}{\partial{B}}\right)_A$, can be expressed as

\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{\partial{B}}{\partial{C}}\right)_A = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{M} {   \left(\dfrac{\partial{B}}{\partial{A_k}}\right)_{\substack{A_{1,\ldots, j, \ldots, M}\\ k \neq j }}  \, \left(\dfrac{\partial{A_k}}{\partial{C}}\right)_A    }
\end{align}

The subscripts on the parenthesis above indicate which variables are considered constants with respect to the given partial derivative.  In particular, $\substack{A_{1,\ldots, M}\\ k \neq j }$ indicates that all of the $A_j; j\in 1,\ldots, j, \ldots, M$ are considered constants, save the partial derivative in question (i.e, the $k^\textrm{th}$ one).

**Discussion**

Question: Why did I start by asking for a a derivative and end up with a partial derivative?

Answer: The initial question appears to be ill-posed. As opposed to finding the derivative, what I really saught all along was $\left(\dfrac{\partial\left\{B(A_1, \ldots, A_M)\right\}}{\partial\left\{C(A_1, \ldots, A_M)\right\}}\right)_A$. I am purposefully leaving the title as a misnomer because like myself, there might be others who would not think to search for a constrained partial derivative.

**Conclusion**

Beyond the solution to my question, this question offers a demonstration that the ratio of two differentials is not a derivative.

**Referencess**

[1] [Is $\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}$ not a ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio/775261#775261)

[2] [Differentiating with respect to a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/differentiating-with-respect-to-a-function)

[3] CRC Math Encyclopedia, Edition XX, 336.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I write the solution as a constrained partial derivative as 
\begin{align}
\left(\dfrac{\partial{B}}{\partial{C}}\right)_A = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{M} {   \left(\dfrac{\partial{B}}{\partial{A_k}}\right)_{\substack{A_{1,\ldots, M}\\ k \neq j }}  \, \left(\dfrac{\partial{A_k}}{\partial{C}}\right)_A    }
\end{align}