# Partial derivative of a function with respect to another function

Tags: partial-derivative

$f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are differentiable functions.

How do I find an expression of partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$ while holding $x$ constant?

Is it just $\frac{df}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dg}$?

(it is not a duplicate of another question, which concerns the derivative of $f(u,v)$ with respect to $u(x,y)$ or $v(x,y)$, which is explained by the chain rule).

My attempt
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differentiating with respect to a function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/differentiating-with-respect-to-a-function)

Comment: Why do you want to differentiate a function with respect to another function?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin No idea, just an idea my professor asked me to think about.

Comment: Select two differentiable functions for both $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ and take the derivative of one with the other... what happens? Remove the arbitrariness and compute an actual example.

Comment: Furthermore, if it is something your professor asked you to think about. Stop and actually think about what you are doing when you take a derivative.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin The professor asked to keep the problem as arbitrary as possible.  However, I've added my own attempt, but I'm not sure is it true or not (and I have a test soon so I don't have time to check with my professor).

Comment: Good job! All done and dusted!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291376/differentiate-with-respect-to-a-function