# Differentiating with respect to an expression rather than a variable

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

suppose if I have the following equation:

$$f(x) = \sin(3x)^{4} + 4x^{2} + 3g(x)$$

What is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $\sin(3x)$?

Does $\frac{df(x)}{d\sin(3x)} = 4\sin(3x)^{3}$ even though the terms $4x^{2}$ and $3g(x)$ are functions of $x$?

Thanks.

Comment: Well the equation u=sin x is solvable for x, and lets you write x as a function of u: what you want to do is then simply the chain rule.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks for your hint. so the new equation with u = sin(3x) would be $f(\frac{arcsin(u)}{3})= u^{4} + \frac{4}{9}(arcsin(u))^{2} + 3g(\frac{arcsin(u)}{3})$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiating with respect to a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/differentiating-with-respect-to-a-function)

Comment: To be honest, the notation is bad. You need to define exactly what you mean by $df/dh$ for a function $h$.

Comment: @AnneBauval No, that is for muti-variable differentiation of a function. I am looking at single variable differentiation of a function rather than a variable as such, I do not want to be confused with many other equations.

Comment: If we define $h_1(x,y,z)=y^4+4x^2+3z$ and $h_2(x)=(x,\sin(3x),g(x))$, and we define "$df/d\sin(3x)$" to mean $\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}(h_2(x))$, then $\frac{df}{d\sin(3x)}(x)=4\sin(3x)^3$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Anyway, thanks for sharing that question. I have already figure out how to solved the problem.

Comment: If we define $h_1(x)=x^4+4(\arcsin(x)/3)^2+3g(\arcsin(x)/3)$ and $h_2(x)=\sin(3x)$, and we define "$\frac{df}{d\sin(3x)}$" to mean $\frac{d(h_1\circ h_2)}{dx}$, then the $u$-substitution works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is straightforward if you only decide if you need a partial or a total derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $\sin(3x)\,.$ Simple plain calculus in the end.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{d}{d\sin x}f(x)=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}f(x)}{\frac{d\sin x}{dx}}$$

Comment: Oh, I did not know you could do chain rule by dividing derivative terms. Interesting.

Comment: @KohYiMinJason - You can't, in general, not without more explanation of what things mean, like Mariano's explanation involving inverting.

Answer (score 0):

i think that if you are going to derive with respect to something containing x then you can't treat anything containing that x as it is a funtion of it
to derive this you just need to make a simple substitution

let: $\alpha=$$\sin(3x) $$\Leftrightarrow x=$$\frac13$$\arcsin($$\alpha)
$

then the function becomes in terms of $\alpha$ as:
$f($$\alpha)=$$\alpha^4 + $4($\frac13$$\arcsin($$\alpha))² + $$3g($$\frac13$$\arcsin($$\alpha$))

which now you can derive easily with the power and chain rule to get:

$\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(\alpha)=4\alpha^3 + \frac{8}{9}\frac{\arcsin(\alpha)}{\sqrt{1-\alpha²}} + \frac{g'(\frac{1}{3}\arcsin(\alpha))}{\sqrt{1-\alpha²}}$

now you can try and substitute $\sin(3x)$ back in to get:

$\frac{d}{d\sin(3x)}f(x)=4\sin(3x)^3 + \frac{8}{9}(\frac{3x}{\sqrt{1-\sin²(3x)}}) + \frac{g'(x)}{\sqrt{1-\sin²(3x)}}$

you can also make it look a little better by replacing $\sqrt{1-\sin²(3x)}$ with   $\cos(3x)$

and that's it

Comment: Your answer ignores the possibility that OP did not clearly mention if a total or a partial derivative is required. The entire post is of very low quality and should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $f(x)=\sin^4(3x)+4x^2+3g(x)$, I would solve by differentials like that:

$$df=(12\sin^3(3x)\cos(3x)+8x+3g'(x))dx$$
$$d\sin(3x)=3\cos(3x)dx$$
$$\begin{align}
\frac{df}{d\sin(3x)}&=\frac{12\sin^3(3x)\cos(3x)+8x+3g'(x)}{3\cos(3x)}\frac{dx}{dx}\\
&=4\sin^3(3x)+\frac83x\sec(3x)+g'(x)\sec(3x)
\end{align}$$