# Can you find a derivative of a function $f(x)$ with respect to something that isn't $x$?

Tags: derivatives

I am not sure how to phrase this exactly, but an example of what I'm talking about is finding the derivative of $x^4$ with respect to, say, $x^2$. I was just thinking, maybe you could use some substitution to find the answer, and make $x^2=a$, and thus find $d/dx$ of $a^2$ with respect to $a$, and hence $d/d(x^2)$ of $x^4$ would be $2x^2$. Can you do this? Or is it illegal?

Comment: $$
\frac{{dx^4 }}{{dx^2 }} = \frac{{\frac{{dx^4 }}{{dx}}}}{{\frac{{dx^2 }}{{dx}}}} = \frac{{4x^3 }}{{2x}} = 2x^2 
$$

Comment: damn so i was right, im a genius

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291376/differentiate-with-respect-to-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^2.$

Then, by the inverse function rule, $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}=\frac1{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}}.$$

By the chain rule, \begin{align}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dy}\left(x^4\right)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x^4\right)\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}\\&=4x^3\cdot\frac1{2x}\\&=2x^2.\end{align}

Comment: interesting method. just a question - what exactly does this derivative represent?

Comment: @ryang You linked the same thing twice.

Comment: @TheDeadCreator Good question; related rates: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related_rates) and [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/relatedrates.aspx).

Comment: Hi @ryang, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435979/585488